# Reply to a new case with description included in email response by default

Tags: apex, case, email2case

When I create a case with email2case functionality and go into a case feed view and click `reply` or `reply all` - initial description is attached to email response.

There're some issues we experience with email2case and I want to have more control and manually process leads / contacts creation, long story short:

I want to create a case programically either with api or apex and set subject and description of a case. But when I hit `reply` or `reply all`, email body of response is empty and has no description attached. How to set it up so that reply has description attached by default?

== Some ideas: ==

1. Create a case and then update it with dummy data using email2case (by case unique id), therefore, replies will have description attached by default functionality.
2. Somehow set a default template which will pull description.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fully answer your question and use case, but I was able to get the 'Reply' and 'ReplyAll' functions, set an Email Template per my company's demands. 
I implemented QuickActionDefaultHandler, and slightly adjusted the example which is provided here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_QuickAction_QuickActionDefaultsHandler.htm

Let me know if you need any more assistance. 
Ido.